# SQL Conversion from Teradata to Snowflake with Format '9(13) V9(2)'

Tags: sql, teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am in the process of Migrating Teradata SQLs to Snowflake.
In Teradata, I have encountered one of the column in the query is casted like below

`CAST(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS FORMAT '9(13) V9(2) ') AS CHAR(15))`

With the blog post [here](https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/tools/casting-zoned-decimal-into-readable-decimal), this format is to stored mainframe specific data into readable format.

I did not find anything related to this FORMAT in the Snowflake and unfortunately I could not even see the data to do workaround but I could figured out the workaround with sample data like below

`CAST(RPAD(LPAD(COLUMN_NAME,13,0),15,0) AS CHAR(15))`

Can anybody tell me if this can be done with other way or the one I am using is correct? Please let me know if need more description.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code does would help expand the people who can help you beyond those who are familiar with both Teradata and Snowflake.

Comment: I don't think Snowflake `TO_CHAR` supports the `V` implied decimal point. I suppose you could use a format like '0000000000000.00' and then remove the "." as well as the leading blank (and potentially minus sign if there could be negative values).